# ffmpeg multiple overlays at different times

Tags: ffmpeg, overlay, delay

I have written a bash script which cycles through various RTMP live streams and switches every thirty seconds.
I have a PNG sequence which plays at the start of the video (blindRev-%d.png). A blind is pulled up, revealing the stream.

28 seconds later, I would like it to come back down to cover the stream so that when the next stream is loaded, it retracts to reveal the next stream in sequence once again (blind-%d.png). I've tried using itsoffset to accomplish this. No audio is required.

However, only the first PNG sequence is played, the second never seems to happen.

The command I am using is:

```
ffmpeg -i rtmp://localhost/live/$stream -i blind/blindRev-%d.png -itsoffset 28 -i blind/blind-%d.png -filter_complex overlay -an -f flv rtmp://localhost/live/All
```

What am I doing incorrectly?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to loop the images and then alter their timestamps.

```
ffmpeg -i rtmp://localhost/live/$stream -loop 1 -i blind/blindRev-%d.png
  -filter_complex [1]setpts='mod(N,50)/25/TB+30*trunc(N/50)'[im];[[0][im]overlay
  -an -f flv rtmp://localhost/live/All
```

I assume that your sequence has 50 images, and that you want the overlay to start every 30 seconds.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I forgot to put -t 00:00:30.0 onto that command. The stream runs for 30 seconds and then the script moves onto the next one, so therefore it would need to play the first overlay at the start of the video and then play the second overlay at about 28 seconds into the video rather than just putting the overlay onto the video every 30 seconds. The overlay is 50 frames, yes.